# Effect of oxidation on solar cell bus-bars

Tags: solar-cell, efficiency, interconnect

Does oxidation of bus-bars have a major effect on the performance of the solar cells? I've been trying to find some answers but no outcome yet.

Comment: The subject line talks about PV cell bus bars and the body talks about PV cells in general. he cells and the whole panel are different again. You should change one or other so they reflect what you really want to know. The answers are different.

Comment: Bus-bars are part of the solar cell... So if the performance of the bus-bar is affected the performance of the cell going to change. I have never referred to solar panels neither in the subject or the question.

Comment: The term bus bar is a many splendoured thing. It here could have meant current collector on the PV cell or the interconnecting strips that you solder or weld or otherwise bond to he cells. In a real world situation you care about all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Subject: Effect Of Oxidation On Solar Cell Bus-Bars
>
> Text: Does oxidation have a major effect on the performance of the solar cells? I've been trying to find some answers but no outcome yet.

I'll extend the question beyond either and talk about whole PV (Photovoltaic)  panels and the component parts. I'll talk mainly about crystalline silicon laminated panels as these are the industry standard and are known to be able to meet or exceed 25 year lifetimes **when properly built**.

Oxidation, and Oxygen, are major factors in PV panel lifetimes. (Chemists will tell you that you don't need oxygen for oxidation, and having potential differences makes this easier to occur, but in most cases Oxygen is a major part of PV cell and panel degradation.

A major degradation and failure source in PV panels can be stuff + water + Oxygen. If you can keep the water and/or the Oxygen out you will get little corrosion. You cant. A PV panel of multiple cells laminated between two sheets of low iron tempered glass using industry standard good quality EVA laminating material will have it's water vapor levels equalised with external ambient, typically within weeks to maybe a few months. For the rest of the 25 years you have to deal with water INSIDE the panel. Oxygen comes in faster.

PV cell materials (silicon wafer, on wafer current collectors, current collecting conductors, ...) WILL corrode and fail when exposed to liquid water and oxygen. An additional factor is that the industry standard EVA laminating material. EVA is used in the form of a clearish plastic film (also used in some glasshouse applications) that melts under temperature and pressure over a controlled time period and crosslinks and bonds the whole assembly together.

Have to do other stuff ... will complete later ...

Points:

LIQUID water against cells does damage. Water vapor much less so.

A bonding agent that binds with no voids and that has low water absorption works best. Water permeability is much much less important. Keeping LIQUID water off panel materials is a major aim.

Not all EVAs are created equal. Breakdown products can be a long term corrosion source.

Waterproof backsheets are needed BUT do not keep out water - only slow it down. Even iof backshet is perfect (eg float glass) water comes in sideways along the EVA seal. There are new matrials offerered to replace EVA. May be good BUT great care needed.

Specialised silicone rubbers may be superior to EVA+ glass. DFow Corning PV6100 is one such.

More anon ...

Comment: Nice one.... I am actually planning to analyze adverse effects of oxygen on the solar cells. just put them in open (one laminated and one open) for around six months check for the effect on the generation.. will get back with results after few months :)